# Update GUI from a non-GUI-Thread -> Not working with BeginInvoke()

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, begininvoke

I have created a simple WindowsForms-Application with one `button` and one `label`.
If I click the button then the label should display the numbers from 1 to 100000.

But if I click the `button` then the `GUI` freezes till the program counted to 100000 and then the label displays 100000 and the GUI stops freezing.

The counting from 1 to 100000 is executed in a new thread (not the GUI thread) and then changing of the `labeltext` I try with `BeginInvoke`, but it don't works...

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            new Thread(DoSomethingExpensive).Start();

        }

        void DoSomethingExpensive() {

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                this.label1.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
                    label1.Text = "" + i;
                    }
                    ));
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Vkt0rS. That wouldn't really change anything in this case, or provide any particularly helpful tools.  While it's nice in general, BGW just isn't really designed to handle this particular problem.

Comment: @Servy How so? This seems like the exact use-case that a bgw is designed for. You want to send an update to the UI thread during a long-running process.

Comment: @DanielMann Why don't you go try it out for yourself and see if you can re-write this code into an effective and working solution that leverages the BGW's tools.  You'll see it has the exact same problem as is seen in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeginInvoke` is asyncrhonous.  This means that it queues the action to take place in the UI thread and then continues on with its business.  Queueing up 100,000 actions in the UI thread doesn't actually take long at all.  It in fact takes quite a lot less time than actually executing each of those actions.  This means that the queue ends up being flooded with all of these requests to update the text.  When a new request is added, say, a request to repaint the form to display the new value, or respond to a mouse click event on the form, it is placed at the end of the queue, after those many thousands of other requests.

If you use `Invoke`, instead of `BeginInvoke`, then the background worker won't move on to queue the next item until the previous item has finished running in the UI thread, keeping it from getting ahead of the UI thread and flooding the queue.  This means that any other UI events, such as the events to actually repaint the screen, don't have more than at most one item in the queue to wait behind.

Comment: This isn't very accurate, BeginInvoke() requests are placed at the end of the message queue as well.  Problem is that there are *two* queues, the message queue that Windows implements and the invoke queue that stores the delegates.  A single invoke will cause the UI thread to consume *all* of the invoke queue entries.  Which never stops if there is yet another one ready to be invoked when the previous delegate target finishes executing.

Comment: @HansPassant  I don't understand your last sentence.  Could you rephrase it?

Comment: It loops until the invoke queue is empty.  It never gets empty.

Comment: @HansPassant Why wouldn't it get empty?  Unless there is some other unrelated operation that is filling the queue with tons and tons of delegates, in which case, that would be the problem to fix.

Comment: Because executing the delegate target takes more time than the worker thread needs to add another one.

Comment: @HansPassant If using `BeginInvoke`, yes, the worker thread will be able to continue appending requests when they have not yet been executed.  By using `Invoke` instead, you prevent that situation from arising.  Or are you critiquing my explanation of the problem, and not the proposed solution, in which case, how does what you are describing differ from what I have described, because I don't see the two as meaningfully different?

Answer (score 0):

For every value a thread context switch should be done. If you do this 100000 times, the UI Thread is freezing. This is caused by the asynchronouse calls. The UI thread is nothing else doing than EXECUTE this delegates. There is no time for the UI to get work items from the MessagePump unitil the last delegate is invoked. The Update of the control is triggered via WindowMessages by the MessagePump.

Now the value of the last delgate is set to the control.

Comment: `For every value a thread context switch is done.`  No, actually, that's not the case.  In fact, if it were, *then the code would actually work*.  The problem is that there *isn't* a context switch quickly enough.  You are correct in saying that the UI thread is doing almost nothing besides executing these delegates, but it won't necessarily execute all of them before doing anything else (it potentially will though).  You also don't explain at all how the OP can go about *fixing* his code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a naive ReactiveUI way:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    IDisposable subscription;
    IObservable<long> sequence;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (subscription != null)
            subscription.Dispose();

        sequence = Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))
            .Take(10000); // generate a timed sequence

        subscription = sequence // act upon the sequence
            .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
            .Subscribe(x => label1.Text = x.ToString());
    }
}
```

depends on the current [reactiveui-winforms](http://www.nuget.org/packages/reactiveui-winforms/) package