# Update GUI components from Begininvoke

Tags: c#, user-interface, begininvoke

So I have a very basic Windows Application where I want to count from 1 to 10000
and show the numbers in label:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                {
                    label3.Text = i.ToString();
                });
            }
        });

        thread.Start(); 
}
```

The problem is that the label text doesn't update and shows only the last loop counter i.e. 9999. Is BeginInvoke called on UI thread? Why  does not the label get updated correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: You want the number to increment every time you click the button?

Comment: @LaneL No,I want to press a button and see the numbers going up to 10000

Comment: Use Background worker instead... refer details here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: @Sanket I know about Backgroundworker, I want to know why the Begininvoke doesn't work out.

Comment: You created a fire-hose bug.  You are slamming the UI thread at a very high rate.  Too fast for it to keep the label updated, invokes have a higher priority than paints, *and* too fast for your eyes to see the changes.  You'll have to slow it down, use Task.Delay(15) for example.

Comment: Similar questions posted here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459486/update-gui-from-a-non-gui-thread-not-working-with-begininvoke?rq=1

Comment: @Hans Passant, Task.Delay(15) didn't make any changes, or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Because BeginInvoke is an asynchronous call, you're sending too many updates to the text box for it to update fast enough, by the time the text box has got around to drawing, it's already counted up to 10000!

You can synchronously update the text, that is, the calling loop will halt until the text box has updated and finished, use Invoke instead of BeginInvoke.